# PHPUnit - Call to undefined function http_parse_headers() error

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I have the following code

`protected function parse($header) {
     $headerArr = http_parse_headers($header);
     foreach ($headerArr as $key => $value) {
         echo $key.'=>'.$value;
    }
 }`

where $header is a http header. This code is in a PHP Class in a symfony2 project. I can execute it in a browser an get the expected results the keys and values of the parsed header like this

- Response Code=>200
- Response Status=>OK
- Date=>Sun, 13 Jul 2014 21:39:51 GMT
- Server=>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
- Last-Modified=>Wed, 26 Mar 2014 22:51:46 GMT
- Etag=>502-4f58a50290480
- Accept-Ranges=>bytes
- Content-Length=>1282
- Content-Disposition=>attachment; filename= mvc.zip
- Keep-Alive=>timeout=5, max=100
- Connection=>Keep-Alive
- Content-Type=>application/zip

The problem is when i try to run a unit test for the function parse(), the PHPUnit can't find the http_parse_headers() function an throws "PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function http_parse_headers()

How is this posible?
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

A quick search of the PHP manual shows that http_parse_headers is part of a pecl extension: PECL pecl_http >= 0.10.0

Your server and your command line php versions must be different.  The php manual has a work around but hopefully you can just update your command line version.

Comment: My server is my own computer, so I'm running the command line in the same place than my server. My PHP version showed by php - version command is PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4 (cli) (built: Apr  9 2014 17:08:27)