# Why http_parse_headers is undefined in my cli script?

Tags: php, http, command-line-interface, pecl

I have spotted some dependency issue working with  PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5.

Trying to parse some HTTP headers but ended with:

> __ [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException]                                                 Attempted to call function "http_parse_headers"__

I've solved it by installing pecl_http extension but most important was to put:

> extension=json.so

above

> extension=http.so

More info here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67140

but when I'm trying:

> php -r 'echo defined("http_parse_headers") ? "yes" : "no";'

I gets 'no' :/

http extension is on libs list printed by php -m

I have installed via:

> pecl install pecl_http
>
> php -r 'echo phpversion("http");'

gives me 2.1.4 strange...

Any advice please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596949/phpunit-call-to-undefined-function-http-parse-headers-error different php.ini for cli?

Comment: @Steve so why php -m return me http on list?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pl/function.function-exists.php return false too...

Comment: Similar problem here... using ondrej's PHP PPA - echo phpversion('http');
2.5.6

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a new syntax

```
\http\Header::parse($yourHeaders);
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34792452/288568