# http_parse_headers with PECL_HTTP

Tags: php, apache, http, configuration

I wanted to use [`http_parse_headers`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-parse-headers.php) So, I've installed dependency `pecl_http(2.4.3/2.2.5)` and call `http_parse_headers` function with no success.

`function_exists()` always fails is there anything that I'm missing here?

I'm using

**CentOS 6.7 (Final)**

**Apache 2.4.16**

**PHP 5.6**

**Update 1**

Here is the Code!

```
<?PHP
    if(function_exists("http_parse_headers")) echo 'Function Exists';
    else echo 'Function Not Exists';
?>
```

**Update 2**

here is the `php.ini`

```
......
......
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension="memcache.so"
extension="raphf.so"
extension="propro.so"
extension="http.so"
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

**Update 3**

Here is the output of `phpinfo()`

[image: output of phpinfo()]

Comment: had you restarted apache after installation?

Comment: Yes I've restarted using `service httpd restart`

Comment: Did you enable it in your php.ini?
Add these: extension=raphf.so, extension=propro.so,
extension=http.so

Comment: Yes, please check update 2

Comment: Does adding curly braces help? `<?php
    if(function_exists("http_parse_headers")){ echo 'Function Exists';
    }else{ echo 'Function Does Not Exist';}
?>`  ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php  and as shown in: http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-parse-headers.php  does `print_r(http_parse_headers($headers));`  show anything?  Maybe this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368574/how-to-get-the-functionality-of-http-parse-headers-without-pecl

Comment: @Steve Please read the question carefully. If you don't have a solution. Avoid commenting.

Comment: check the output of `phpinfo()` or `get_loaded_extensions()` or do `php -ri http` on the cli. does it list the extension? If it doesn't list the extension, make sure you edited the right php.ini, e.g. the one that is given in `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Yes, I've checked using `get_loaded_extensions()` and all the following extensions are loaded `raphf, propro, http`. Although, `php -ri http` gives following output `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in Command line code on line 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, After a long long search I found that

[Version 2](https://mdref.m6w6.name/http) of `PECL_HTTP` library is COMPLETELY INCOMPATIBLE with [Version 1](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.http.php) None of the HTTP functions exists in [Version 2](https://mdref.m6w6.name/http)

This is NOT stated ANYWHERE in the docs on [PHP.net](http://PHP.net).

By the way, [Version 2](https://mdref.m6w6.name/http) is a completely OOP interface and drops support for all the functions listed [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.http.php) in the docs.

If you are looking for the functional API, use [Version 1](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.http.php)

So, as suggested by Ricardo you need to use

```
http\Header::parse($yourHeaders);
```

to parse header and

```
new http\Cookie($yourCookies);
```

to parse cookie etc

Answer (score 8):

The PHP docs are incorrect. Version 2 of the library is incompatible with the functions listed in php.net.

Reading the [new documentation](https://mdref.m6w6.name/http) you now have to use [HTTP::parse](https://mdref.m6w6.name/http/Header/parse) as such:

```
http\Header::parse($yourHeaders)
```